# VBA to insert into macro to choose the save path for exporting files

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a workbook without about 30 or so sheets and i've got a macro to save a selection from each sheet as a text file. My code is below and currently just has C:\data as the path. What i want to do is have a bit before the 'for each' loop that prompts the user to select the save path (a team drive) and then the loop carries through and exports all the files to that path. Can anyone help me?

Thanks, Rich

```
Sub Exporttotext()
Dim c As Range, r As Range
Dim output As String
Dim lngcount As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Name As String
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    output = ""
    For Each r In sh.Range("O2:O500").Rows
        For Each c In r.Cells
         output = output & c.Value
        Next c
        output = output & vbNewLine
    Next r
    Name = sh.Name
    Open "C:\data\" & Name & ".txt" For Output As #1
    Print #1, output
    Close
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example code to launch path selection UI.

```
Sub test()
    Dim strFolder As String

    strFolder = GetFolder("C:\temp\")

    '/ Opens in that folder
    'strFolder = GetFolder("C:\temp\")

    If strFolder <> "" Then

        MsgBox strFolder

    End If

End Sub


Function GetFolder(Optional strPath As String = "") As String

    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fldr
        .Title = "Select Output Report Location"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If strPath <> "" Then
            .InitialFileName = strPath
        End If
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an inputbox to accomplish this:

```
Sub Exporttotext()
Dim c As Range, r As Range
Dim output As String
Dim lngcount As Long
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Name As String
Dim sSharedPath As String
    sSharedPath = InputBox("What is the path", "Destination", "\\MyPath\")
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        output = ""
        For Each r In sh.Range("O2:O500").Rows
            For Each c In r.Cells
                output = output & c.Value
            Next c
            output = output & vbNewLine
        Next r
        Name = sh.Name
        Open sSharedPath & Name & ".txt" For Output As #1
        Print #1, output
        Close
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I was actually after the dialog box to pop up where you navigate to the filepath. But your input box has helped me with something else i was struggling with so thank you!

Comment: No prob :D you did write select, I guess I just didn't read enough into it ;)